# Automatic email notification when a product is back in stock

Tags: magento-1.9, crontab

I have activated the option "Sign up to get notified when this product is back in stock"

Magento 1.9.1 give the possibility to subscibe to a product that is out of stock to let be informed by email when the product is available again.

But Magento don't send email, i think it depends on cronjob.

I also tried with this extions to manage cronjob http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html but nothing happens

Can you suggest me how to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a cronjob to manage product stock alert.

Here is the way to test  :

1 - subscribe to stock alert on frontend ( your entry will be store in product_stock_alert table )

2 - add stock to the product  you have subscribed to and set this product in stock ( this is the condition to send the email)

3 - launch cronjob (via Aoe Scheduler ) catalog_product_alert

Answer (score 0):

I tried but the mail is not sent.

At the point 3) i enter in System ->Scheduler ->Scheduled configuration

I see "catalog_product_alert" as enable.
I select it and select action->run now i get this message:

```
Ran "catalog_product_alert" (Duration: 0 sec)
"catalog_product_alert" messages:

Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer
```

but no email is sent.

What i wrong?

Comment: Hi, Try to check product_alert_stock table and find your alert by email. Check  fields : send_count , status and send_date to know if your alert should have been send. If it is set to 1 , maybe it is a mail problem  then check exception.log and system.log in your magento var/log folder . If it is set to 0 make sûre the product id in this table is set to is_in_stock  = 1 and has qty > 0

Comment: hi, in product_alert_stock table the record is creating correctly. After i run Aoe Scheduler nothing happens and the field send_count still is set to (0 zero) , send_date (null), status (0 zero) and i have a message "Last heartbeat is older than one hour. Please check your settings and your configuration!" . And i don't know why if i luch this link www.mywebsite.com/index.php/productalert/add/testObserver the email is sent. Maybe cron is not set correctly?

Comment: Got a cron problem today  . Maybe you have the same problem check your server crontab  and make sure cron.sh is called :
"crontab -l" on your server

Comment: Sorry i don't know, ... how to do this? i use windows server and IIS 7.5

Comment: I know to do this only on linux but it seems like on windows you need to call cron.php via scheduled task manager : see this post
http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/395-setting-up-cron-jobs-in-magento
It's important your cron.php need to be called every 5 minutes so that your cron task will be executed like catalog_product_alert

Comment: Yes the problem was  a scheduled task for windows. Now is ok, i configured a scheduled task and the "product alert" email has been sent. However i cannot still use AOE scheduler i get this error in log file "PHP Warning:  ini_set(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (D:/) in D:\myPath\app\code\community\Aoe\Scheduler\Model\Schedule.php on line 635". If you have any idea and if i could solve also this problem should be fantastic. Thank you very much

Comment: Good News !
Can you copy / past  a bit of code in D:\myPath\app\code\community\Aoe\Scheduler\Model\Schedule.php on line 635 ?
Is it this one ? 
https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/blob/master/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php

It seems like you need to create error log file : var/log/cron.log but I'm not sure ..

Comment: Yes the file is that one!...i wrote to the author he reply to me "...please check the open_basedir configuration in your php_ini (and unset it)...". I didn't  yet try to make this changes in php.ini file maybe i will do next days but i think it will solve the problem. As soon as i will try i will let yu know